BigQuery - Aggregate over JSON column
We have table in BQ where two of the columns are like this:
 | cost Float | labels JSON | 
 | 10         | {"key1":"value1", "key2:"vaue2"} |
 | 20         | {"key1":"value3", "key2:"vaue2", "key3:"vaue4"} |
....

We need to be able to do SUM(cost) over the unique combination of key-value pairs across the table.
Example output:
 10 "key1:value1"
 20 "key1:value3"
 30 "key2:vaue2"
 20 "key3:vaue4"

Is this possible to be done in BQ ?
SELECT
    t.key,
    t.value,
    SUM(t.cost) AS total_cost
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
          CAST(key AS STRING) AS key,
          JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(label, CONCAT('$[', key, ']')) AS value,
          cost
        FROM
          `PlayGround.table1`,
          UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(label, '$[0]') AS BIGNUMERIC))) AS key
    ) AS t
  GROUP BY 1, 2

gives an error "Argument 2 to JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR must be a constant expression at [22:38]"

Use below
select sum(cost) as cost, replace(kv, '":"', ':') as kv
from your_table,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(labels), r'"[^"]+":"[^"]+"')) as kv
group by all   

if applied to sample data in your question, output is

